# Laptop freezing after Ubuntu kernel 5.11.0-34-generic

Tags: drivers, 20.04, kernel, fan, overheating

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon 7th gen with Ubuntu 20.04 installed. The current kernel version installed is `5.11.0-34-generic`. Few days ago, my laptop froze completely and after a forced shutdown the laptop was stuck at the Ubuntu logo. This didn't get solved no matter how many times I force restarted the laptop.

Later I enabled Secure Boot and was able to login without freezing. But now my CPU cores seem to be overheating and the fan is working at maximum speed draining the battery quickly. The core temperatures are displayed as > 80.0°C all the time and fan RPM is 4600+.

Any idea why this is happening and any solutions to this? I tried to change the kernel version (to 5.8.0-63-generic) through grub but when I do that none of my drivers work (network, bluetooth, touchpad, etc.).

Comment: Do you have free space on your system disk?

Comment: Yes. I have more than 500gb available.